# Print length of raw string value of an list of strings

Tags: python, list, rawstring

I have a list of strings that looks like this:

`elements = ['abc\n', 'def\t']`

I want to get the length of the [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html), i.e., before it compiles the escape characters. I know how to do that if they were in a single variable, for eg:

```py
org = 'abc\n' # Original string
len(org) # Will give 4
raw = r'abc\n' # Raw string
len(raw) # Will give 5 as it counts the \n as 2 chars
```

I tried doing this, but it is not working, any help will be appreciated.

```py
for e in elements:
    print(len(e)) # Gives length of compiled string
    print(len(re)) # Throws error
    print(len(r+e)) # Throws error
```

Comment: The `r` tells how to store the literal string, once it is stored you can't change it, you can't access its "raw format"

Comment: You should do some more research about strings and raw strings. The `r` specifier simply says that backslashes must be interpreted as literal backslashes instead of escaping the next character. There isn't some "raw string" that is stored before compiling the escape characters in the original string -- it interprets `\n` as the newline character.

Comment: "the length of the raw string, i.e, before it compiles the escape characters" There is no such thing. First off, the escape characters aren't "compiled"; they are parsed. Second, that happens before any of your code has a chance to run. Third, any given string could be created in a variety of different ways - it doesn't necessarily have any such source to consider. The `r` prefix works by *changing the rules* that Python uses to parse the literal source. It is not some kind of operation on an already existing string.

Comment: Once you understand what a raw string actually is, a simple solution would be to count the number of special characters that need to be escaped and add that to the length of the string.

Comment: One possibility that *might* suit your purposes is to consider the *representation of* the string, which you get using `repr`. This will include *a possible* set of escape sequences that *could produce* the original string from source code. It will also include beginning and ending quotes.

Comment: Right, I understand I need to read more into raw strings, the comments are really helpful in understanding the difference is parsed vs compiled. I can confirm the answer given below by @Abhi_J works as well.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Thanks I used the `repr` function, it worked with most escape characters such as `\n` and `\t`. However, it does not seem to work with `\"` or `\x27` as it still parses it into a `"` and `'`.

Comment: Well, yes. That's what I was saying: if your string has a `'` in it, then there is no way to determine whether that was produced by a `'` in the original code, or `\'` (inside a single-quoted string), or `\x27`, because that information *doesn't exist*. The string *didn't necessarily come from "original code" at all*, so the question is nonsense. You are trying to create a cow from a pile of hot dogs, and they might not even be beef.

Comment: Basically, "the raw string" that you're looking for doesn't exist. Ever, no matter what the string is. It Does Not Work That Way(TM). You must learn to distinguish between things in themselves, and representations of things.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to encode the strings with '*unicode_escape*' to get the desired result

**Code:**

```py
elements = ['abc\n', 'def\t']

for e in elements:
    print(len(e.encode("unicode_escape")))
```

**Output**:

```
5
5
```